# Modificar objeto de datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy Utilizando el plugin `datatables.js` para mostrar los datos obtenidos de una consulta en una tabla, actualmente las columnas que se muestran en la tabla son fijas y las muestro con el siguiente codigo:

```
            $('#example').DataTable({
                "ajax": 'php/resultados_adquiridos.json',
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "ID" },
                    { "data": "FECHA"},
                    { "data": "T1" },
                    { "data": "T2" },
                    { "data": "T3" },
                    { "data": "T4" },
                    { "data": "T5" },
                    { "data": "T6" },
                    { "data": "T7" },
                    { "data": "T8" },
                    { "data": "T9" },
                    { "data": "T10" },
                    { "data": "T11" },
                    { "data": "T12" },
                    { "data": "T13" },
                    { "data": "T14" },
                    { "data": "T15" },
                    { "data": "T16" },
                    { "data": "T17" },
                    { "data": "T18" },
                    { "data": "T19" },
                    { "data": "T20" },
                    { "data": "T21" },
                    { "data": "T22" },
                   
                ],
```

pero ahora me solicitan que cada checkbox represente una columna y si el checkbox esta seleccionado esa columna se tiene que mostrar al presionar el boton submit,pero no tengo idea de como realizar esto,alguien podria indicarme que camino podria tomar,gracias

```
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T2'/><label for="text1">T2</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T3'/><label for="text1">T3</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T4'/><label for="text1">T4</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T5'/><label for="text1">T5</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T6'/><label for="text1">T6</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T7'/><label for="text1">T7</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T8'/><label for="text1">T8</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T9'/><label for="text1">T9</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T10'/><label for="text1">T10</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T11'/><label for="text1">T11</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T12'/><label for="text1">T12</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T13'/><label for="text1">T13</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T14'/><label for="text1">T14</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T15'/><label for="text1">T15</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T16'/><label for="text1">T16</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T17'/><label for="text1">T17</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T18'/><label for="text1">T18</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T19'/><label for="text1">T19</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T20'/></td><label for="text1">T20</label></li>
                    <li><input type='checkbox'  name='checkbox[]' value='T21'/></td><label for="text1">T21</label></li>
                    <li><input type='checkbox'  name='checkbox[]' value='T22'/></td><label for="text1">T22</label></li>
                    <button id="enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  ">Obtener datos</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Una vez aclarada la duda, he actualizado mi ejemplo:

```js
var dataUrl = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/SagnalracSO/repoJD/employees";

function mostrarTabla() {

    $("#example").show();

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: dataUrl,
          dataSrc: ''
        },
        destroy: true,
        columns: [
          { 
             data: 'id',
             visible: $("#cbId").is(":checked")
          },
          { 
             data: 'firstName',
             visible: $("#cbFirstName").is(":checked")
          },
          { 
             data: 'lastName',
             visible: $("#cbLastName").is(":checked")
          },
          { 
             data: 'position',
             visible: $("#cbPosition").is(":checked")
          },
          { 
             data: 'office',
             visible: $("#cbOffice").is(":checked")
          },
          { 
             data: 'age',
             visible: $("#cbAge").is(":checked")
          },
          { 
             data: 'startDate',
             visible: $("#cbDate").is(":checked")
          }
        ]
      });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="cbId" checked="checked" />
<label for="cbId">Mostrar/Ocultar Id</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbFirstName" checked="checked" />
<label for="cbFirstName">Mostrar/Ocultar First Name</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbLastName" checked="checked" />
<label for="cbLastName">Mostrar/Ocultar Last Name</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbPosition" checked="checked" />
<label for="cbPosition">Mostrar/Ocultar Position</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbOffice" checked="checked" />
<label for="cbOffice">Mostrar/Ocultar Office</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbAge" checked="checked" />
<label for="cbAge">Mostrar/Ocultar Age</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cbDate" checked="checked" />
<label for="cbDate">Mostrar/Ocultar Start Date</label><br>
<br>
<button onclick="mostrarTabla()">Mostrar Tabla</button>
<br><br>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%; display: none;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<br>
```

Comment: creo que no me explique bien,he modificado la pregunta,ojala sea mas comprensible,gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: @LuisLIRE: Disculpa la confusión, ya actualicé mi ejemplo. Es eso lo que estabas buscando?

Comment: mas o menos,exactamente lo que busco,es que antes de mostrar la tabla con los datos,el usuario tenga que seleccionar los checkboxes correspondientes a las columnas que desea consultar y en base a ellos,se muestren las columnas deseadas

Comment: @LuisLIRE: Ah ok! Era al momento de su inicialización. He vuelto a editar mi respuesta. Dicen que la tercera es la vencida ;)

Comment: ejecute el codigo de ejemplo pero me da problemas,y no he podido ver si el funcionamiento );

Comment: @LuisLIRE: Qué problema te da? A mi me está corriendo bien. Podrías intentar en otro navegador solo para revisar si ahora si puedes ver la ejecución completa por favor?

Comment: me manda un error que dice que no se puede reinicalializar la tabla

Comment: la primera ve que ejecuto el ejemplo funciona bien,pero cuando vuelvo a seleccionar por segunda vez,ya me manda el error

Comment: @LuisLIRE: Tienes toda la razón. Si presionas el botón más de una vez sale ese error porque el DataTable solo se puede inicializar UNA vez. Ya solucioné ese problema incluyendo el atributo `destroy: true` Qué tal ahora?

Comment: funciona mucho mejor,muchas gracias por la ayuda!!